Is there something wrong with this function to exclude entries in a conditional format in Excel?
I am trying to format a column to display duplicate entries, but I would like to exclude #N/A as that is what shows up when there is no data to display that is meaningful. I have a memo from an order for parts that displays a part number, and I've used a function to separate that part number out into a new column, but now I would like to highlight all duplicates, but #N/A is my null display essentially, so I would I go about excluding that from the conditional format.
I have already tried the following functions in the conditional formatting rules:
=AND($M5 <> "#N/A", COUNTIF($M$5:$M$2564,$M5) > 1)
=AND($M5 <> "*#*", COUNTIF($M$5:$M$2564,$M5) > 1)

Both of these can seem to get rid of the highlight on some of the entries of #N/A, but for some reason neither work entirely and there are still many entries of #N/A staying highlighted.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Use ISNA to test for #N/A, or ISERROR generally to check for an error value.

To elaborate on @BigBen comment, your functions are testing for the string "#N/A". Is that what is generated by your formula that fills those cells? Or is it the error value #N/A? Testing for an error value is NOT the same as testing for a string value.

And to just triple elaborate what this means for you, is your formula should be =AND( iserror($M5)<>TRUE, COUNTIF($M$5:$M$2564,$M5) > 1)

It looks like you may be dealing with "#N/A" in various forms. So combining the excellent elaborations in comments:
=IFS(ISNA($M5), FALSE, COUNTIFS($M5,"*#*N*/*A*"), FALSE, TRUE, COUNTIF($M$5:$M$2564,$M5) > 1)

Or
=AND(NOT(ISNA($M5)), NOT(COUNTIFS($M5,"*#*N*/*A*")), COUNTIF($M$5:$M$2564,$M5) > 1)

and, why not,
=NOT(OR(ISNA($M5), ISBLANK($M5), COUNTIFS($M5,"*#*N*/*A*"), COUNTIF($M$5:$M$2564,$M5) = 1))

Result:

